# Parse JSON feed to HTML with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I am trying to parse the following JSON feed into HTML, but not getting any results.

```
{
  @name: "App name",
  license: [
    {
      @name: "Apache License 2.0",
      component: [
        {
          name: "Product 1",
          url: "http://www.url.com"
        }, {
          name: "Product 2",
          url: "http://www.url.com"
        }, {
          name: "Product 3",
          url: "http://www.url.com"
        }
      ],
      licensetext: " license text here"
    }
  ],
  isProjectComplete: "true"
}
```

With this jQuery:

```
$.getJSON("https://json-feed-url.json", function (data) {
  var jsondata = json;
  var output = "<ul>";
  for (var i in jsondata.events) {
    output += "<li>" 
      + jsondata.component[i].name + " " 
      + jsondata.component[i].url + "--"
      + jsondata.license[i].licensetext
      + "</li>";
  }

  output += "</ul>";
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = output;
});
```

To this div

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

Not sure why its not parsing correctly. Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/cL7v4znp/9/).

Comment: Not sure your JSON is valid at all, validate [here](http://jsonlint.com/). A valid JSON would start with `{"@name": "App name"`Also, on the other hand, for cross-domain requests you would need JSONp.

Comment: Your keys need to be quoted: e.g. `"@name"` instead of `@name`, `"license"` instead of `license`, etc.

Comment: @skobaljic, the JSON is valid, and is coming directly from an AWS instance. I'd share the URL, but it has a secret key that is required to view the feed.

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors, starting from invalid JSON you posted. Corrected it should work as you can see [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/cL7v4znp/3/) and below:

```
var yourJson = {
    "@name": "App name",
        "license": [{"@name": "Apache License 2.0",
            "component": [{
            "name": "Product 1",
                "url": "http://www.url.com"
        }, {
            "name": "Product 2",
                "url": "http://www.url.com"
        }, {
            "name": "Product 3",
                "url": "http://www.url.com"
        }],
            "licensetext": " license text here"
    }],
        "isProjectComplete": "true"
};

function convertJson(data) {
    var jsondata = data;
    var output = "<ul>";
    for (var i in jsondata.license[0].component) {
        output += "<li>" + jsondata.license[0].component[i].name + " " + jsondata.license[0].component[i].url + "--" + jsondata.license[0].licensetext + "</li>";
    }

    output += "</ul>";
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = output;
};

convertJson(yourJson);
```

You should be more careful and you should learn to use debugging tools more effective.

Comment: my JSON feed is correct. I'm using the JSON View extension in chrome to view my feed(which takes out the double quotes)

I'm not sure of the syntax to change from `var yourJson = {}` to using the URL

Comment: Thanks for the help. I updated the jsfiddle(with actual url removed), but its still not pulling the feed in. It is when I have the actual data, but not with the URL.

Comment: Working on two different versions, but for now using the static content. Also trying to figure out how to apply an `href` to the url output

Comment: I am encapsulating the url with `"<a href='license[0].component[i].url'>" + jsondata.license[0].component[i].url + "</a>"`, but its not applying the URL accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68916/discussion-between-skobaljic-and-matt).

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in jsFiddle

```
// WRONG
$.getJSON("http://jsonurl.json";, function (data) {
// CORRECT
$.getJSON("http://jsonurl.json", function (data) {
```

Comment: Maybe I'm getting old, but the WRONG and CORRECT versions look exactly the same... I think you meant to remove the semicolon in the CORRECT version?

Comment: Yes, I meant to remove the semicolon.